# Android app development (with XML) can the id part get a simpler value?

Tags: android, xml

I am studying Android application development with XML in Android Studio at an educational institution. I saw a code like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id=”@+id/MU_EditText_id”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap-content"
    android:hint="Please login e-mail adress"
    android:textSize="15px"
    android:inputType="textEmailAdress"
    android:maxLines="1"
/>
```

The `android:id` part caught my attention. Why is this id so long? Couldn't there be a simpler use? Thanks in advance for your valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id can be as long or as short as you like it to be. `android:id=”@+id/` is necessary, but everything after that is the id that your ui element is referenced by and is up to you to name. The id could also just be a character, but the best practice is to name your ids corresponding to what they are or what they are used for.

Comment: It's a good manner to give self-explanatory names, if you use multi-module architecture it may be the module name prefix and then the name. Short names often lead to misunderstanding of element purpose.